# SQL - Calculating Year Over Year Growth for monthly returns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has monthly data in the form of:

```
Date | Value
2018-06 | 100
2018-07 | 105
2017-06 | 90
2017-07 | 92
```

What would be the best way to take this data and calculate a year over year return for each month?
I would want it to look like:

```
Date | YoY growth
2018-06 | 0.11111
2018-07 | 0.1413
```

Comment: Is `Date` a text column or an actual date?

Comment: It's a text column. I originally converted daily data to monthly data, and used to_Char(date,'YYYY-MM') to group it by month.

Comment: Instead of text data, convert each data into date object, for example: `{'2018-06-01', '2017-06-01'}` then group data by dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT ON month to choose months only. Then use LEAD windowing function on the reversed list (via ORDER BY d DESC) to get the year prior to current year

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5be39/2

```
select
    distinct on ( date_part('month', (d || '-01')::date) )  -- get the months only

    -- ORDER BY d DESC sort the list from most recent to oldest.
    -- so LEAD here actually refers to previous year

    d,
    v,               
    lead(v) over(partition by date_part('month', (d || '-01')::date) order by d desc), 

    ( v / lead(v) over(partition by date_part('month', (d || '-01')::date) order by d desc) )
    - 1 as YoyGrowth


from progress
```

Output:

```
|       d |   v | lead |          yoygrowth |
|---------|-----|------|--------------------|
| 2018-06 | 100 |   90 | 0.1111111111111111 |
| 2018-07 | 105 |   92 |  0.141304347826087 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply parse the date and use `lag()`:

```
select date, value, prev_value,
       (value - prev_value) / prev_value as YOY_growth
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by right(date, 2)
                              order by left(date, 4)
                             ) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be full proof. For example lets say, we have entries for 2018-06 and 2016-06 but not 2017-06 then the query will give wrong results. 
It would use data from 2016-06 for 2018-06 yoy calculation.

Comment: @arman . . . The question strongly suggests that the data is for months ("a table that has monthly data in the form of").  If you have a question with missing data, then ask a question with your data and an appropriate explanation.