# How to increment PSQL table by one year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `table` with:

```
Company|Date | Value
Best Buy| 2018-06 | 100
Best Buy|2018-07 | 105
Best Buy|2017-06 | 90
Best Buy|2017-07 | 92
```

I want to calculate the year over year growth to get something like:

```
Date | YoY growth
2018-06 | 0.11111
2018-07 | 0.1413
```

When I go to join the two tables like so:

```
SELECT y1.company, y2.Date, (y2.value/y1.value -1) as YoY_growth
FROM table as y1
LEFT JOIN table as y2
ON y1.company = y2.company AND (y2.date = y1.date + interval '1 year');
```

What's the proper way in PSQL to increment y1.date by 1 year to get year over year growth. The table is getting filled with Nulls currently

Comment: What is the data type of `date`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  to_Date(to_Char(date, 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM')

Comment: I mean, is it a `date`, a `timestamp with time zone`, a `timestamp without time zone`, a `text`, ...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry it's just a `date`

Comment: But `2018-06` is not a possible value for a `date`. What is the "day" part? Maybe your problem lies there.

Comment: Already answered this same question on your old question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439059/sql-calculating-year-over-year-growth-for-monthly-returns/55439313#55439313). Don't know why the answers there are not good enough for your use case. By any chance, is this a homework that requires you to use `JOIN` instead?

Comment: It's best to make the Date field a date type instead of text/varchar, so you can easily tap the rich date functionalities provided by postgresql. Instead of '2018-06', store it as a real date, '2018-06-01'. Then when presenting it to users, just extract the year and month, and present it as '2018-06'

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT y1.company, y2.Date, (y2.value/y1.value -1) as YoY_growth
FROM table y1 LEFT JOIN
     table y2
     ON y1.company = y2.company AND
          (y2.date || '-01')::date = (y1.date || '-01')::date + interval '1 year');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really store your date field as date type. This answer would suffice. Otherwise, I give up, lol :D

`DISTINCT ON (company, date_part('month', y1.date))` picks the months only for each company. So at most, you have 12 rows only for each company.

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/751ad/4

```
CREATE TABLE progress
    ("company" varchar(7), "date" date, "value" numeric(18,4))
;


INSERT INTO progress
    ("company", "date", "value")
VALUES
    ('BestBuy', '2017-06-01', 90),
    ('BestBuy', '2017-07-01', 92),
    ('BestBuy', '2018-06-01', 100),    
    ('BestBuy', '2018-07-01', 105)
;

SELECT 
     distinct on (y1.company, date_part('month', y1.date))    

     y1.company, 

     to_char(
         first_value(y1.date) 
         over (partition by y1.company, date_part('month', y1.date) 
               order by y1.date desc),
         'YYYY-MM'
     ) as date,     

     (y1.value/y2.value - 1) as YoY_growth

FROM progress as y1
LEFT JOIN progress as y2
ON y1.company = y2.company AND (y2.date = y1.date - interval '1 year');
```

Output:

```
| company |    date |         yoy_growth |
|---------|---------|--------------------|
| BestBuy | 2018-06 | 0.1111111111111111 |
| BestBuy | 2018-07 |  0.141304347826087 |
```