# PostgresSQL - Calculating Year Over Year Growth with data having missing entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions

I have a table that has monthly data, with missing entries for few months, in the form of :

data_table

```
entity_id | Date(data_type: date) | Value
1         | 2018-06-01            | 100
1         | 2018-07-01            | 105
1         | 2017-06-01            | 90
1         | 2016-07-01            | 92
```

The entry for 2017-07 doesn't exist in the table.

What would be the best way to take this data and calculate a year over year return for each month? I would want it to look like:

```
entity_id | Date       | Value
1         | 2018-06-01 | 0.11111
1         | 2018-07-01 | null
```

ie. if the prev year value is not present it shows null

Note: I can't edit the table. Also, the original table has lot of entities where each entity has values like above. The original table size is also big.

I have tried few approaches like one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439059/sql-calculating-year-over-year-growth-for-monthly-returns) which suggests to use lag function like

```
select date, value, prev_value,
       (value - prev_value) / prev_value as YOY_growth
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by right(date, 2)
                              order by left(date, 4)
                             ) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is not null
```

But it doesn't solve missing entries case. In comments, people suggested asking a new question.

Also, one approach is to use the join query,

```
select t1.*, t1.value as prev_value
from data_table as t1 left join data_table on t1.date = t2.date - INTERVAL '1 year'
```

But I don't want to use it as this is a resultant table. Therefore, it will make it slower to compute same table two times.

Any better options?

Comment: Are you really storing the dates as strings in `yyyy-mm` format, or you are actually using the `date`  datatype?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dates with `generate_series()`, then use window functions:

```
select date, (value - lag_value) / lag_value as yoy
from (
    select
        d.date,
        t.value,
        lag(t.value) over (partition by right(d.date, 2) order by left(d.date, 4)) as lag_value
    from (
        select to_char(
            generate_series((min(date) || '-01')::date, (max(date) || '-01')::date, interval '1 month'),
            'yyyy-mm'
        ) as date
        from mytable
    ) d
    left join mytable t on t.date = d.date
) t
```

Comment: got it. But the table is huge. It has multiple entities and each entity has values like in data_table. So the query will be too slow.

Comment: @arman: this should not be really slower than the initial query. The query can be adapted to take in account multiple entities - but you should have mentionned that in the first place when asking the question, and show the corresponding data.

Comment: I agreed. I missed this point in the question. Apologies for that. Have updated the question.

Comment: I have updated the question properly. Can you help with it now as to how to incorporate multiple entities too in the query?